# Typescripit type guard returning that values exist

Tags: javascript, typescript, class

I have a method on a class

```
isReadyToSumNumbers() {
    return Boolean(
      this.arithmeticOperation && this.slots["1"] && this.slots["2"]
    );
  }
```

which obviously indicate that if all 3 values exist it returns true.

then I have another method that uses this method and looks like this:

```
if (this.isReadyToSumNumbers()) {
      const newValue = this.arithmeticOperation(
        this.slots["1"],
        this.slots["2"]
      ).toString();
...
```

But typescript is showing an error that `this.arithmeticOperation can be undefined` thus I thought of doing a type guard but all examples are irrelevant because you can type guard a class  | .

I wonder how it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

The best option is to just inline the checks. Typescript can figure out inline checks a lot better than it can those hidden in methods.

Another option is to use custom type guards and change the type of `this` with the type guard:

```
class Test {
    isReadyToSumNumbers(): this is Test & {
        arithmeticOperation: (a: number, b: number) => number;
        slots: {
            1: number,
            2: number
        }
    } {
        return Boolean(
            this.arithmeticOperation && this.slots["1"] && this.slots["2"]
        );
    }
    m() {
        if (this.isReadyToSumNumbers()) {
            const newValue = this.arithmeticOperation(
                this.slots["1"],
                this.slots["2"]
            ).toString();
        }
    }

    arithmeticOperation?: (a: number, b: number) => number;
    slots: {
        1?: number,
        2?: number
    }
}
```

Comment: TIL: There are type guards on `this` ... great answer as always :)